# Set value in core config table Magento 1.9 issue

Tags: magento-1.9, core-config-data

I am going to set the core_config_data table value for flat catalog products via code but when I print in log it always shows wrong values.

```
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('catalog/frontend/flat_catalog_product', '0', 'default', 0);
Mage::log("Flat Catalog Disbale After ... ".Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/flat_catalog_product',0),null,'apply.log',true);
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('catalog/frontend/flat_catalog_product', '1', 'default', 0);
Mage::log("Flat Catalog Enable After ... ".Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/flat_catalog_product',0),null,'apply.log',true);
```

Kindly suggest, I need to disable then enable for some code segment but it returns wrong values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with below code :

```
Mage::getModel('core/config')->saveConfig('catalog/frontend/flat_catalog_product', '0', 'default', 0);
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but in both log print it shows enable, I need to first disable the do some stuff then again enable it.